# Does there exist an algorithm for divisibility by a prime number for all prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Say we have $p=3$, a prime, there exist an algorithm to check whether a number is divisible by $3$ without testing if $3$ divides that number. The algorithm is simply summing the digits and dividing by $3$. My question is now, can we tell if a number (e.i. does there exist an algorithm) is divisible by a prime number by only looking at the digits of the number being divided? Do these algorithms exist for all $p$ — primes?

Comment: Well,  one could cheat and say sure,  just give the number in base $p+1$,  then the sum of all the numbers must be divisible by $p$ for the number to be divisible by 3 :)

Comment: no, $7$ divides $49$ but does not divide $94$.

Comment: They exist for each prime.  Some like $2$ and $3$ and $5$ and $11$ are relatively simple.  Others like $7$ are not much easier than straight division (remove the last digit, double it and subtract from what was left; if that is divisible by $7$ then yes, if not then then no, if unsure then repeat; so for example with $434$ you do $43-2\times 4 = 35$ which is divisible by $7$ so $434$ is divisible by $7$).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact, for any number $n$, there is a deterministic finite state machine which recognises digit strings representing numbers divisible by $n$.

The idea is that the states are $S = \mathbb{Z} / (n \mathbb{Z})$, and one transitions from state $j$ to state $10j + i \mod n$ upon reading digit $i$. Make the starting state $0$ and the only accepting state $0$.

This implies that for all $n$, there is a regular expression representing exactly numbers divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Do long division the way you were taught in school, but don't bother saving the final result. That's basically how that standard "divisible by 3" trick works (along with one or two minor optimisations), and that's how you can do it for any $p$ relatively quickly.